# footnote in section title beamer

Tags: beamer, sectioning, footnotes

With the following I am trying to have a separate slide for every section title, to which I would like to add a footnote. Unfortunately, the footnote does not display at the end of the slide. Also, the footnote number is 2 instead of 1:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!30,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor*{title}{bg=lightgray!5,fg=blue!75}
\usepackage{array}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bibentry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
\usepackage{hyperref,longtable}
\usepackage{graphics,epsfig,lscape,setspace,url,setspace,morefloats,appendix,comment,booktabs,color}
\usepackage[labelfont=sc, singlelinecheck=false, font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage[
backend=bibtex,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
\setbeamertemplate{bibliography item}[text]
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black
}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{romannum}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}[square]
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{appendixnumberbeamer}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{xspace}
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{title}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsectionhead\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\title[Presentation]{A presentation}
\author[someone]{some\inst{1,2}}
\institute[]{\inst{1} somewhere1 \\ \inst{2} somewhere2\
}
\bigskip
\date{whenever}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Section title\footnote{A footnote attempt}} % 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I use `footnote[frame]{the footnote}`, the footnote is repeated on each frame of the section, which I do not want (and I still get 2 instead of 1). How to fix this?

Comment: Please rationalize and reduce your example; this is far from being minimal. BTW, no need to load `color`, `xcolor`, `graphics` *and* `graphicx`, as well as `amsmath`. And I'm fairly confident that `epsfig` was already obsolete when I started using LaTeX some 20 years ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The footnote got repeated on every frame of the section because the section name is shown in the headline and thus present on every frame. You can avoid this by

- specifying an alternative version of the title using the optional argument of `\section[short version]{long version}`
- using `\insertsection` instead of `\insertsectionhead` in your section page to get the long version of the section name

Alternatively you could avoid the problem by choosing a headline which does repeat the current section on every frame, e.g. `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{bg=blue!30,fg=black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=lightgray!5,fg=blue!75}
\setbeamercolor{section}{parent={title},fg=black}

\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begin{frame}
  \vfill
  \centering
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,shadow=true,rounded=true]{section}
    \usebeamerfont{title}\insertsection\par%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vfill
  \end{frame}
}

\title[Presentation]{A presentation}
\author[someone]{some\inst{1,2}}
\institute[]{\inst{1} somewhere1 \\ \inst{2} somewhere2}
\date{whenever}

\begin{document}

\section[Section title]{Section title\footnote[frame]{A footnote attempt}} % 


\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: great solution!

Comment: @user9875321__ You're welcome!